# Has Supergirl ever been in a Superman movie?

Tags: dc, superman, supergirl

I have no idea if she has and I really want to know. Please tell me.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. She appears in the animated film [Superman/Batman: Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman/Batman:_Apocalypse)

Comment: The cops see this woman shoot lasers out her eyes, exploding the engine of a police car and they immediately jump out and give chase on foot?

Comment: @KyleJones - Cops in Metropolis are not renowned for their smarts.

Answer (score 1):

Never in live-action (she did have a solo movie in 1984, starring Helen Slater). I have heard that the idea was floated for a time of having Slater's Supergirl appear in a movie with Christopher Reeve's Superman - but if that's right it obviously came to nothing. As mentioned, Supergirl did appear in the DC Universe Animated Original Movie *Superman/Batman: Apocalypse* (an adaptation of the comic book story arc *The Supergirl from Krypton*).